# React-Native Native module cannot be null after adding Webviews

Tags: ios, react-native

I am trying to add React-Native Webview in my existing iOS app, but getting issue Native Module cannot be null. I have tried lot of solutions from online community but yet not fixed the issue.

```
'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, RefreshControl, WebView, Text} from 'react-native';
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <WebView
                originWhitelist={['*']}
                source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}
            /> 

        );
    }
}
```

Error:

> Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring module
>   "node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/WebView/WebView.ios.js",
>   which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be
>   Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid:
>   expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for
>   composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export
>   your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed
>   up default and named imports.

Comment: Can you share the code what you have written, 'coz it would be helpful to other developers to check where the issues would be.

Comment: Also please share the error what you are getting now

Comment: 'use strict';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, RefreshControl, WebView, Text} from 'react-native';
export default class Dashboard extends Component {
 render() {
  return (
   <WebView
    originWhitelist={['*']}
    source={{ html: '<h1>Hello world</h1>' }}
   /> 
   
  );
 }
}

Comment: Unhandled JS Exception: Requiring module "node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Components/WebView/WebView.ios.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be Unhandled JS Exception: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Comment: You should not add the code to comments directly as per stack overflow policies. Add them in question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall the `node_modules`

`rm -rf node_modules && npm install`

Comment: I already tried this. Also changed versions in package.json. But solutions are not working in my existing project which is into objective-c and swift. I tried with new project where i can able to render webview successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Had this issue and the steps I took were:

1) restart

2) rm -rf node_modules && npm install

3) restart